# How to monitor actions in Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

working on an application that wants to now integrate active directory. should be able to import users from active directory, as well as reflect changes for example if a user is created/deleted/update etc in active directory the user should be created/deleted/updated in the database table the application reads from. I kno that LDap can be used to query the Active Directory to import users, but not sure how to cater for the other areas.

Comment: Why copy the user information into your own table instead of just querying AD?

Comment: the application reads from a table so if i import Ad users i need to then have them inserted to the database table

Comment: reflect changes for example if a user is created/deleted/update etc in active directory the user should be created/deleted/updated in the database table the application reads from. code to do this...

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/isrpfeplat/archive/2010/09/20/using-the-dirsync-control.aspx

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The previously supplied link is a good one. Of those ideas, my general suggestion is to use DirSync. It allows you to poll AD with a token and get all changes since the previous poll. All you have to do is remember the token (it comes back with the response to the query).

Comment: thanks much i am going to try and work with that, hopefully its works well